# CSS ul li changed from list to table in mobile view - 3 items per row using CSS only if possible

Tags: html, css

I have a side nav bar which has a html structure as follows:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3
       <ul class="sub-nav">
           <li>Sub Item 1</li>
           <li>Sub Item 2</li>
           <li>Sub Item 3</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And sits to the side of the desktop / tablet page and shows this list.

Item 1

Item 2

Item 3

Sub Item 1

Sub Item 2

Sub Item 3

Using a media query for phone size screens I want it to change to showing only the top menu items in this fashion:

```
       |        |       
Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3
_______|________|_______
       |        |
Item 4 | Item 5 | Item 6
       |        |
```

I know how to `float` and `display: block` the `li` items to force them to go horizontal, but how do i get every fourth to go to a new line, only using CSS please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them a set width.

So if you set them to `width: 33.33%` you have them taking up 1/3 of their container. If they all can't fit on the same line they will break to a new one.

Comment: Hi @powerc9000 nice approach, but then I cannot set other specific CSS such as the borders. I am looking at `:child(n+3)` approach.

Comment: @TheRealPapa you very well can. It is called box-sizing. It may not work on all browers but neither does `:child(n+3)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @TheRealPapa What you will be looking for is `border-box`: The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin.

Comment: thanks for the help. The border-box piece I know about I was referring to having different border on each box based on position. Just like my drawing, the top middle box has left, right and bottom, but the left box has only bottom in this scenario.